# Most recent backup not available when attempting to restore iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

I am trying to restore my most recent backup onto my iPhone, but I can only see old backups when I click `Restore`. My most recent backup does appear in iTunes under Preferences.

How can I access that one, as the other is actually 8 months old? My iPhone has been stolen I am keen to recover my most recent data.

Answer (score 1):

*You can only restore a backup onto an iPhone, iPad, iPod or WATCH that is running the same, or a more recent version of its operating system.*

If your latest backup isn’t showing up as an option when attempting to restore your iPhone, first set it up as new, and update to the latest version of iOS. Then try another **Restore**. Your backup should show up then.

Comment: yeah, I have a more recent version and still the backup option won't show

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try some itunes backup extractor software, like [Dr.fone](http://www.lovemediasoft.com/ios-data-recovery.shtml) or [iphone backup extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/)To see whether read the most recent backup file. If yes, you can use it to extract the data in the backup to your computer.